# Complicated list slicing

Tags: filtering, list-manipulation

Say I have a list with the structure

```
list = {{1, {x1, y1, z1}}, {2, {x2, y2, z2}}, {3, {x3, y3, z3}}, ...}
```

I would like to slice it such that I end up with

```
{{1, y1}, {2, y2}, ...}
```

Is there a clean way to do this with `Part`? Ie, something along the lines of

```
list[[All, {1,{2,2}}]]
```

(which clearly isn't the right levelspec syntax). But, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to slice it properly.

I know this is ultimately possible doing something like

```
Map[{#[[1]], #[[2, 2]]} &, list]
```

but this is a bit clumsy and I'm hoping there is a straight-forward list slice I can use instead. Not to mention, I clearly don't fully get how Mathematica implements `Part`, and I keep running around in circles on the help page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
list = {{1, {x1, y1, z1}}, {2, {x2, y2, z2}}, {3, {x3, y3, z3}}};
```

In addition to your current method

```
{#[[1]], #[[2, 2]]} & /@ list
```

You can use a number of additional methods, including

```
Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], list[[All, 2, 2]]}]
{#, #2[[2]]} & @@@ list
{#, #2 & @@ #2} & @@@ list
Transpose@Extract[Transpose[list], {{1}, {2, All, 2}}]
list2 = list; list2[[All, 2]] = list2[[All, 2, 2]]; list2
(* or, more simply, list[[All,2]]=list[[All,2,2]] if you want to modify the list *)
list3 = list; list3[[All, 2, 0]] = #2 &; list3
```

to get

```
{{1, y1}, {2, y2}, {3, y3}}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I take it there isn't a way to get that slice just using `Part`?

Comment: @Neal, afaik not as of v10 :) Maybe someone more knowledgable could suggest a way to overload `Part` to accept an argument pattern like `{1,{2,2}}` (which, btw, is very natural, also the pattern i thought should work).

Comment: I just wanted to clarify in the event you are brand new to Mathematica- in my mind, the first method kgular illustrated is pretty much only using part. The shorthand notation for part is [[x]]. It is true that technically, he is also using list {} and map /@ to get your desired solution, but this is a very typical way of doing list manipulation in Mathematica. I don't see Wolfram ever adding on to the Part function so that you only have to use part in place of the aforementioned method. @kguler, +1 for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

I find extracting the parts and then combining them (e.g. with `Transpose`) to be fast and general.  kguler already showed this but again for reference:

```
{list[[All, 1]], list[[All, 2, 2]]}\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{1, y1}, {2, y2}, {3, y3}}
> ```

Pattern matching is another general method, though often not quite as fast.

```
Cases[list, {a_, b_} :> {a, b[[2]]}]
```

> ```
> {{1, y1}, {2, y2}, {3, y3}}
> ```

Since your example only requires modification of the `{x1, y1, z1}` part you could also use [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[#[[2]] &, list, {All, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, y1}, {2, y2}, {3, y3}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

**Using `Replace`**

```
list /. {a_, b_List} :> {a, b[[2]]}
```

or

```
Replace[list, a_List :> a[[2]], {2}]
```

> `{{1, y1}, {2, y2}, {3, y3}}`

Answer (score 3):

Mapping `Thread` on the list is useful in a lot of such cases:

```
(Thread /@ list)[[All, 2]]

(* {{1, y1}, {2, y2}, {3, y3}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method

```
list // Thread[{#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2, 2]]}] &
```

> {{1, y1}, {2, y2}, {3, y3}}